# Both didEnterRegion and didDetermineState called

Tags: ios, geofencing

I am using a region monitor feature in my app. I want to get notified when the user enters the region and also if he is already in the location.

So implemented both the location manager's `didEnterRegion` and `didDetermineState`.

Now the problem is when I enter the geofence area, it notified twice. One from didEnterRegion and another from didDetermineState inside.

What is the best solution? I need to notify only once when entered.

Comment: post your all location manager related delagate method implementation code.

Comment: @KrishnarjunBanoth I am just using Localnotification for triggering the alert. In this case it triggered twice, one from enter and another from determineState.

Comment: Actually it is the common behaviour of location manager itself. First delegate method calls didDetermineState then it conforms by calling didEnter region, Simply put your logic in didEnterRegion.

Comment: So both didDetermineState with state Inside and didEnterRegion get called when enter region?

Answer (score 0):

Please use only "didDetermineState". It will be called while you enter/exit the region. Use the below code inside "didDetermineState".

```
switch state{
       case .inside:
       print("INSIDE")
       break
       case .outside:
       print("OUTSIDE")
       break
       case .unknown:
       print("UNKNOWN")
       break
}
```

And to determine current location, use "didStartMonitoringFor". This function will be executed after the below line is called.

```
locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
```

Inside "didStartMonitoringFor" use the below line:

```
locationManager.requestState(for: region)
```

This will again call "didDetermineState" and will give your current state "INSIDE/OUTSIDE"